# How to search for text in a file ignoring newlines?

Tags: text-processing, grep, search, newlines

I'd like to search for text that may be split over several lines in a file. A grep that would ignore line breaks and return the matching span of lines.

e.g. I would be searching for `is an example file`, and expect it to be found in the following file:

> This is
>   an
>   example file.

Not to depend on leading or trailing spaces, entirely ignoring all forms of white space might be best (ideally, treating any sequence of white space as a single space).

---

One non-ideal solution is `tr '\n' ' ' | grep`, that discriminates between matches and non-matches, but doesn't show the match, nor deals well with big files.

Comment: on SO (no definitive answer) : http://stackoverflow.com/q/1858312/1449460

Comment: As a side note, emacs' search seems to do the job (`isearch-forward`)

Comment: So does Vim's: `/This\_sis`.  For more details: `:help \_s`.

Comment: Add this line at the end of your search line:
tr -n "\n"
This will remove all new lines.
Hope this help!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The GNU `grep` can do it

```
grep -z 'is\san\sexample\sfile.' file
```

To fulfill some points which arise in comments there are some modifications to script:

```
 grep -oz '^[^\n]*\bis\s*an\s*example\s*file\.[^\n]*' file
```

Regarding huge files I have no imagination of memory limitation but in the case of problem you are free to use `sed`

```
sed '/\bis\b/{
          :1
          N
          /file\.\|\(\n.*\)\{3\}/!b1
         }
     /\<is\s*an\s*example\s*file\./p
     D' file
```

that keep no more than 4-lines (because 4 words in pattern) in memory (`\(\n.*\)\{3\}`).

Comment: As I’m sure you know, the `-z` option tells `grep` to treat newlines as ordinary text characters, and look for nul bytes to separate records.  In a text file with no nul bytes (i.e., the typical case), `grep -z` will treat the entire file as one line.  So (1) this raises the question of how well it can handle large files, and (2) if it finds a match, it will write out the entire file, giving no clue as to the location of the match.  Also (3) the OP said, “ideally, treating any sequence of white space as a single space,” so you should use `\s+` and add `-E`.

Comment: @G-Man Thank you for comment. Please see edited answer.

Comment: (0) Ah, `-o`; I keep forgetting about that.  Clever way to use it.  (1) Your new `grep` answer begins `^[\n]*`; that’s a typo for `[^\n]*`.  (2) I said `\s+` deliberately.  `be\s*little` will match `belittle`, and `care\s*less` will match `careless`.  But I guess that’s a minor problem.  And, if you don’t want to use `-E`, you can use “the poor man’s version” of `\s+`, namely, `\s\s*`.  (3) Nice `sed` command.  It can fail if there are blank lines (so the four-word phrase can spread over more than four lines); I was able to fix that by adding `s/\n\s*\n/\n/`.

Comment: @G-Man Thank you againg. Your comments are very useful. I have try to post more or less portable code  because famous members everytime push me to do so. Anyway even without `-E` you steel able to use `+` in `\s\+` form. Empty lines inside of pattern seems to be a contrived.

Comment: I was thinking of paginated text documents, like [RFCs](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc793.txt) — ISTR that man pages look like that on some systems (or *did*) — but, on further thought, it occurs to me that most such documents have page header(s) and/or footer(s) that would need to be stripped out before you could hope to `grep` them for phrases.

Answer (score 7):

Try this:

```bash
pcregrep -M '\bThis\s+is\b' <<EOT
This
is
an example
file.
EOT
```

Comment: Do I have to type `\s` 5 times if I search for "this is a very long pattern" ?

Comment: Yes: the point is `\s` matches spaces, and newline is a "space".

Comment: I mean, what if the file is `This\nis a very\nlong pattern`, and I don't know where the line breaks might occur. I'd have to search for `This\sis\sa\svery\slong\spattern`, right ? (which becomes tedious as the length of the pattern increases or is pasted from elsewhere)

Comment: Then you do it like this: `pcregrep -M "$( echo 'This is a very long pattern' | sed 's/ /\\s+/g' )" file`.